# How can I remove the white border from Chart.js pie chart?

Tags: javascript, css, charts

I am using Chart.js pie chart and I'd like to remove white lines between slices. Could someone tell me way to do this ? Thanks in advance

I didn't see anything in the documenation.

[image]

```
    <div class="pie-chart">
         <div id="canvas-holder">
              <canvas id="chart-area" width="250" height="250"/>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what happens if you configure it to use this option `segmentShowStroke : false,` ?

Comment: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart-chart-options segmentShowStroke is the correct answer here.

Comment: @ochi that worked ! very simple fix...thanks...

Comment: I am glad it worked :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**UPDATE**

For newer versions of Chart.js (i.e. 2.2.2 and higher), see [@grebenyuksv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39274338/600486).

This answer was added for an older version of Chart.js (i.e. 1.0.2)

---

*Original answer*

Just configure the options for the chart to hide the line

`segmentShowStroke: false`

Something like this:

```js
//create chart
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

var data = [{
  value: 300,
  color: "#F7464A",
  highlight: "#FF5A5E",
  label: "Red"
}, {
  value: 50,
  color: "#46BFBD",
  highlight: "#5AD3D1",
  label: "Green"
}, {
  value: 100,
  color: "#FDB45C",
  highlight: "#FFC870",
  label: "Yellow"
}];

var options = {
  //Boolean - Whether we should show a stroke on each segment
  // set to false to hide the space/line between segments
  segmentShowStroke: false
};

// For a pie chart
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data, options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: @Sudhanshusharma please expand on your comment... It works for me on Win 7/Chrome and Win7/Firefox.

Comment: may be I have latest version of chart.js. for me most voted answer works

Comment: @Sudhanshusharma that might be why then.. but for future reference: ***Do not deface my answer*** - edits are welcome but a total re-write is a big no-no.  Write your own answer if you happen to disagree someone's answer but completely changing it is not right

Comment: your answer have 5 votes and accepted but for most of the user your answer didn't work. below to your answer have 47 votes. you should include the correct answer also because your answer is accepeted.

Comment: @Sudhanshusharma **So?** my answer was written A) 6 months prior the current highest-voted one. B) the current version did not have a solution at the time and C) using a version accepted by the OP.  Further clarification was indeed needed (which I added) but that does not mean my answer was incorrect or that needed to be defaced.

Comment: How do I don this in doughnut chart ?

Comment: @AshutoshShrestha do you have a question of your own that we can have a look at? I'd be happy to help you with it

Answer (score 117):

In chart.js@2.2.2 (haven't tested for chart.js@2.x.x):

```
const options = {
    elements: {
        arc: {
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, for the current version of Chartjs

Comment: This works for me when using the default colors. If you define custom colors the borders reappears. To remove them you have to add the option segmentShowStroke: false.

Comment: Works for 2.7.3, just to let people know.

Comment: Any idea on how to remove the white border for bar chart? I used the same approach and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 17):

For newest Chartjs like 2.7.2 just put: `borderWidth: 0` in the data

```js
var ctx = $('#progress-chart');
     var data = {
      datasets: [{
          data: [25, 50, 25],
          backgroundColor: ['red', 'green', 'blue'],
          borderWidth: 0, //this will hide border
      }],

      // These labels appear in the legend and in the tooltips when hovering different arcs
      labels: [
          'Red',
          'Green',
          'Blue'
    ]
  };
        var progressChart = new Chart(ctx,{
      type: 'pie',
      data: data,
      options: Chart.defaults.pie
  });
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="progress-chart" width="500" height="250">   </canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js">
    </script>
```

Comment: borderWidth: 0, //this will hide border
Solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

```
Chart.defaults.global.elements.arc.borderWidth = 0;
```

Place it at the beginning of your javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

```
datasets: [
            {
                label: "TeamB Score",
                data: [20, 35, 40, 60, 50],
                backgroundColor: [
                    "#FAEBD7",
                    "#DCDCDC",
                    "#E9967A",
                    "#F5DEB3",
                    "#9ACD32"
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    "#E9DAC6",
                    "#CBCBCB",
                    "#D88569",
                    "#E4CDA2",
                    "#89BC21"
                ],
                borderWidth: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
            }
        ]
```

Comment: When leaving an answer you need to leave more than just a code block. You should explain what this is doing. Also, since this appears to be code it should be in a code block.