# How to remove the inside-border from a single-element doughnut chart? Chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

If there is only one element (segment) in a Pie or Doughnut chart, a single radius line is drawn at the start/end of that single segment.

I want to remove the marked white line to make it a uniformly colored donut/circle, while keeping the outer/inner border lines.

Is there any option to do that? If not, how can one achieve this without painting over canvas?
[image: Sketch of a donut with a single radius line showing]

Comment: why do people minus this question? is this wrong or what? stackoverflow community at its best :)

Comment: You tagged your question with html and css, i expect they want to see your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove the white border from Chart.js pie chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36339791/how-can-i-remove-the-white-border-from-chart-js-pie-chart)

Comment: what code they want to see? this is irrelevant i have asked a simple question, there is no need to write my code here...

Answer (score 11):

You can set `borderWidth` property to 0.

```
options: {
  elements: {
      arc: {
          borderWidth: 0
      }
  }
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prashantpokhriyal/ms19g4fz/4/)

**Update**

If you just want to remove only one border then you can do this using following code

```
datasets: [{
  data: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  backgroundColor: ["#BDC3C7","#9B59B6","#E74C3C","#26B99A"],
  borderWidth: [0, 1, 1, 0]
}]
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prashantpokhriyal/qjzmrvng/)

Comment: but i dont want to hide entire border, because it will make the chart invisible, i just want to hide this one line

Comment: but still it will delete the entire border of one element and make the chart invisible(because there is only one element)

Comment: how is it unclear, i have even marked the line i want to get rid off on a picture......

Answer (score 0):

Just check how many segments you have.

```
const isMultipleSegment = seriesData.filter(val => val > 0).length > 1;
```

If more than one - remove border from chart config.

```
borderWidth: isMultipleSegment ? 2 : 0,
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).