# How can I remove the white border from Chart.js pie chart when all legends are hidden?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js, border

When all legends in the chart.js pie (v2.5.0) chart with border are hidden. A line remains (Border). Is there any way to remove the border or clear the pie chart when all legends are disabled?

tried the [How can I remove the white border from Chart.js pie chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36339791/how-can-i-remove-the-white-border-from-chart-js-pie-chart) on legends clicks when all legends are hidden but it reflects in rendering only after the next event change.

[when all legends are visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeCHZ.png)

[When all legends are hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHaKt.png)

Comment: Can you include relevant code that produced the images above?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue in version 3.2.0 (latest).

```js
const data = {
  labels: [ 'Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow' ],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'My First Dataset',
    data: [300, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
      'rgb(255, 205, 86)'
    ],
    hoverOffset: 4
  }]
};

const config = { type: 'pie', data };

new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), config);
```

```css
.chart-container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart-container">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Here is the version 2.5.0 equivalent with your issue:

```js
const data = {
  labels: [ 'Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow' ],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'My First Dataset',
    data: [300, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
      'rgb(255, 205, 86)'
    ],
    hoverOffset: 4
  }]
};

const config = { type: 'pie', data };

new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), config);
```

```css
.chart-container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart-container">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding `borderWidth: 0` to your dataset config you can remove the white border

Example:

```js
const data = {
  labels: [ 'Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow' ],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'My First Dataset',
    data: [300, 50, 100],
    backgroundColor: [
      'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
      'rgb(255, 205, 86)'
    ],
    hoverOffset: 4,
    borderWidth: 0
  }]
};

const config = { type: 'pie', data };

new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), config);
```

```css
.chart-container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart-container">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```